# Really strange FAT32 file listing problem

Tags: filesystems, mount, ls

I'm mounting a FAT32 drive on my NAS (which has a USB port), and hitting a strange issue when I use the `ls` command on the drive root:

```
ls: cannot access ???²é?u.g: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ?f$?â?.k: Input/output errorPuTTY
ls: cannot access ?21ï??é.ìk?: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ºq`{??ùê.?zï: Input/output error
ls: cannot access +?l`æ~2?.]9: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ??j.é: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ëégö²?è.?« Input/output error
?.¢??: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ??d?¬«ëc.?½f: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ?r??%f.o??: Input/output error
ls: cannot access b}?çb¼=u.?c·: Input/output error
}??..÷p½: Input/output error
ls: cannot access u?;e?j?.
```

I'm not sure why "PuTTy" is thrown in there on the second line.  It is the client I'm using to access the NAS, and I'm running the latest version, but I don't understand what it has to do with the `ls` command.  It goes on like this for a while and then starts listing files that aren't really there along with the files that are:

```
ï¿½?=?^Oaaï¿½.h?=
?*ab^G^S??.?^[?
a?cw??^?*.=?$
ï¿½??aï¿½hï¿½ï¿½.?ï¿½?
??aï¿½?^_j!.?i?
ï¿½?a?m??^U.a^G^?
apps
??^Q??a?y.ï¿½?z
```

I'm running Debian/Lenny (now), but I had the same problem before I switched to Debian on my NAS.  I'm not sure which distro I was running before, I think it was a custom build.

When I plug the drive in, `sdc` and `sdc1` appear in the `/dev` directory.  I'm unable to mount `sdc`, but can successfully mount `sdc1`.  These are the command I've tried using to mount:

```bsh
mount /dev/sdc1 /USB
mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /USB
mount -o umask=0 -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /USB

# Additional
mount -t vfat -o codepage=850 /dev/sdc1 /USB
mount -t msdos -o codepage=850 /dev/sdc1 /USB
mount -t vfat -o codepage=869 /dev/sdc1 /USB
mount -t vfat -o codepage=850,iocharset=iso8859-7 /dev/sdc1 /USB
# ... and combinations of codepage 850, 869, 437 (the common ones)
# ... and combinations of utf8, iso8859-7, iso8859-1
# ... and additional flags such as umask=0, rw
```

If I check the logs after the `ls` command, this is the result:

```bsh
$ dmesg | tail
FAT: Filesystem panic (dev sdc1)
    invalid access to FAT (entry 0x8c31db6e)
FAT: Filesystem panic (dev sdc1)
    invalid access to FAT (entry 0xee786bb9)
FAT: Filesystem panic (dev sdc1)
    invalid access to FAT (entry 0x2f16a272)
FAT: Filesystem panic (dev sdc1)
    invalid access to FAT (entry 0xa8ee938e)
FAT: Filesystem panic (dev sdc1)
    invalid access to FAT (entry 0x6df5a84f)
```

I'll be honest, my Linux knowledge isn't that great — it's limited mostly to basic administrative tasks.  Of course, if I plug the drive into Windows (7) it works fine.

One final note perhaps worth mentioning is that I remember having to use a special tool to format the drive because it was too large for Windows to format it.

**EDIT**

On closer inspection of the drive, all files appear to be present - so where is linux getting all this garbage from?  There are only several files and folders in the root directory on Windows.  Could it be data that has not been properly disposed of?

**EDIT 2**

The same problem in Ubuntu on my Laptop PC.  Both `ls` and the file explorer show these strange file listings.

Comment: Figured out that `PuTTy` from the second line is due to the *answerback from ^E* setting.

Comment: What happens if you try it on a different linux machine? Same results?

Comment: There is something on the filesystem that appears to the Linux driver to be directory entries, but that is clearly not. Either your filesystem is slightly hosed but in a way that the Windows driver tolerates, or the Linux driver is buggy.

Comment: I had this happen too, unmounting the drive was a bit strange, then plugged it into windows and saw this filename madness. unable to delete on windows and linux. was working/mounting fine previously.

Comment: Was the FAT32 drive a MicroSD card by any chance?  I've seen `ls` not work with some (lower quality and fake) MicroSD cards.

Comment: I found a question more similar to my issue - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267259/why-does-ls-sporadically-output-only-in-the-root-directory-of-an-external and posted a workaround, and the fault seems to lie with a bug in darwin's stat64.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a codepage issue. Look in the man page for `mount` - in the `fat` sections, there is a `codepage=` setting you can use.

Also look at the `iocharset=` setting. (And search the web for both.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried various combinations of these and checked the codepage on my Windows machine (850) with no luck.  I've also checked the man pages but not found anything else that helped.

Comment: please update your question with the **exact** commands you tried and what their result was.

Comment: I've updated with as much extra information as I could, the result was exactly the same for each command, except when I set `msdos` as the filesystem short filenames were displayed (as expected).

Comment: I have mounted my drive the same way I always have (linux and windows). seems to be with corruption, not character set. the files are very large, 1.8 GB where a java class file (50k tops) used to be

Answer (score 0):

My guess is either the filesystem is corrupted or may be the data is encrypted/compressed.

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows machine, run `chkdsk /f /`r  - this worked for me. You can probably run `fsck` as root if you don't have access to a Windows machine. I lost all directories which contained the strange files.

Comment: That didn't work for me, in the end the only thing I could do was backup, format and restore.