# Why does "ls" sporadically output only "." in the root directory of an external drive?

Tags: osx, ls, usb-drive

In the root directory of my USB flash drive, sometimes when I run `ls`, the output is normal and it lists the files. At other times, the output is simply one line:

```
$ ls
.
```

If I try `ls -la` at one of those times, I get this:

```
$ ls -la
ls: .: Invalid argument
```

If I run `ls` back to back multiple times, it seems to return either the normal output or the abnormal one basically at random.

`ls` appears to work normally in other directories. `ls $drivename` even appears to work fine from the parent directory, and `ls ..` seems to work fine from a child directory. (Though I can't be 100% sure of the ones that "work normally" since the behavior is indeterminate to begin with.) I tried two other external USB drives and got the same behavior.

What's going on here? I'm on Mac OS X 10.11.3.

**Edit:** Nice idea, but I don't seem to be using an alias, and `/bin/ls` gives the same result.

Comment: This unusual behavior might be the result of a malfunctioning alias.  What happens if you use `/bin/ls`?

Comment: does ls work fine in other directories?

Comment: `/bin/ls` gives the same result, sometimes outputting `.`. `ls` appears to work normally in other directories. `ls NO\ NAME` even appears to work fine from the parent directory, and `ls ..` seems to work fine from a child directory. (Though I can't be 100% sure of the ones that "work normally" since the behavior is indeterminate to begin with.)

Comment: Which file system are you using in those flash drives? Perhaps is some anomaly derived from a windows-based filesystem

Comment: What version of `ls` are you using? `/bin/ls --version` should work

Comment: Hm, `/bin/ls --version` doesn't seem to work on OS X...

Comment: Intermittent hardware failure? Or something's trying to do something to that directory? I'm speculating here. Possible clue, from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File_system&oldid=709353846): "Most file systems store the names of all the files in one directory in one place—the directory table for that directory—which is often stored like any other file." Thus, if there's something wrong with the storage of that directory itself, I'd imagine it would behave something like this. Do you have any disk tools available to you? Have you tried a reformat?

Comment: Some file systems "do not follow the Unix directory-link convention, such as CD-ROM or MS-DOS filesystems or AFS volume mount points." (from https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) Maybe this has to do something with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be a bug in the filesystem driver for FAT32 on recent versions of OSX. This also only appears to occur when the working directory is at the root of the mounted drive. If it's in a subdirectory or anywhere else on the system things seem to work.

There's some interesting discussion in this thread including system traces.
https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/4161

Answer (score 2):

WORKAROUND:  (probably part of what the asker would appreciate even if they didn't specifically ask for it)

Refer to the current directory in almost any way other than `.`.  Example:

`cd` to a subdirectory, and then run `ls` on the parent directory. That is, enter something like this:

`mkdir S; cd S ;  /bin/ls -al ..`

Or refer to it by it's full pathname. Example:

`ls /Volumes/microSD007`

For me, either of these workarounds work (that is, they result in the expected output) when `ls` gives me the same wrong output the OP reported.  (And for me, there's no output in dmesg when `ls` acts oddly.)

I'm seeing the same malfunctions on 10.12.6 in Terminal.app running bash.  Same in `csh` and `sh`, even after setting TERM to vt100.  This workaround works in those shells too.

And I agree there's a bug in `stat64`, as indicated in the `zsh` issue thread Neil points us to.  (I had thought the issue was caused by flawed and/or fake flash memory, and still wonder if that's a factor sometimes.)

I noticed that this bug also affects:

- Emacs' dired mode, because it calls `ls`, and
- `ls` when it's used in Emacs' shell mode.

Comment: I don't understand why Goro made the edits they did, and no edit summary was provided.  I think they made the answer worse, and now I see it's received a -1.

I provided a workaround, removing my 'workaround' indicator makes it seem like I'm claiming/trying to provide a direct answer.  I think I'm offering more than a comment, but less than an answer.  Isn't that to be encouraged?  I'm identified a new; wouldn't an edit summary and a reason for the -1 be appropriate?

Goro also removed a shorter, better answer that I'd added.  I don't get it.

Comment: I'm on the fence; generally answers need to answer the question, not just provide more information, but working around the problem is probably part of what the asker was looking for even if they didn't specifically mention it. Most of the edits seem kind of unnecessary, and at least one definitely messes up the formatting, so I rolled them back. I'm not sure if the post ever had a downvote, but it's currently at 2 upvotes and 0 downvotes

Answer (score 0):

If you sometimes remove the drive, then the answer is that each time you reinsert the drive, you must return to the directory using cd. This is because the file descriptor opened by your shell to read the directory is invalidated when the drive is removed, and is not reinitialized automatically when the drive is reinserted (even though you may have used the drive in another terminal or file manager).

If the drive is never removed, then it may be a hardware problem or maybe some software that unmounts the drive for some reason; you should provide the system logs.